# How do I make sure the line that appears under the first column is moved to the second column on top

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, masonry

I have created a responsive masonry to display some quotes on the page using css inline-block (ref - http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/).

The problem I am having is that somehow the top border that belongs to the 1st element on the 2nd and 3rd row are appearing at the end of the 1st and 2nd row respectively.

See my fiddle here for preview - https://fiddle.jshell.net/8ntahynh/

```css
/*----------------- Testimonials CSS -----------------*/

.masonry {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: .85em;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px #ccc;
}

.testimonial-img,
.center-cropped {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="masonry">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="testimonial-section">
        <blockquote>
          <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>My new door looks a lot like my former front door. I got married and raised my children in that house. Good memories! The front door was made of solid oak and we could open the upper part, which
          we did when we talked to our neighbours for example. It was a pity that we had to move out of that house.
          <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div>
            <span class="footer-source">-
                            <b>Mw. Louwen | </b>Resident at Pieter van Foreest Weidevogelhof in
                            <cite title="Source Title"> Pijnacker</cite>
                        </span>
          </div>
        </blockquote>

        <img src="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/truedoors/wp-content/uploads/truedoors-thestorybehindthedoor-community-quote-1013.jpg" class="center-cropped" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being is that you are using CSS columns to divide up the content. Part of the next column (the top of the box-shadow of the first item) is being displayed at the bottom of the previous column.

Add in some top margin to allow for this extra shadow:

```
.item {
  ...
  margin: .2em 0 1.5em;
  ...
}
```

**Check this out:**
https://fiddle.jshell.net/v1r1g05p/